# how to configure a second domain for images in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

we have a configuration with pound, varnish, apache and TYPO3. every now and then we hava a lot of access to the site and the pound sw gets to its limit.
One idea to loosen the stress was that all images could be fetched with another domain (which gets its own sw).

so the html would be called like http://www.my.domain/folder/page.html and inside the HTML images are referenced like http://images.my.domain/fileadmin/img/image.jpg

what needs to be done so

- the editors could work as before (just access files from /fileadmin/...)
- in the HTML all image(/file)access are generated with another domain?
- make sure all genarated images (*processed*) can be accessed with the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Pound as reverse proxy which does the TLS.

I suggest to reduce the setup and use only Varnish and Apache, so Varnish can handle the requests directly.

Kevin Häfeli wrote an article about it some time ago (in German):
https://blog.snowflake.ch/2015/01/28/https-caching-mit-varnish-tlsssl-zertifikat-typo3/

In case you still want to server the images form an other web server, I suggest to have a look at the file abstraction layer:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FileAbstractionLayerReference/Index.html

Comment: as I'm not the admin and our admin has his own ideas of realizing the setup I will look in the FAL reference.